# What is the database language to get the below result efficiently?

Tags: list, cassandra, set, nosql

Suppose I have a table which has an attribute called literals and I have following data.

[a,b,c,d]

[a,b]

[a,b,c,d,e]

[a,b,c,d,e,f]

I send a search query to get results for [a,b,f]. I don't need unknowns in my result and I just need to get results with known ones. It means my result should be  [a,b]

I have tried Cassandra but it doesn't support negation in lists. Please help me!